# What is the correct way to make the last page appear on pagination?

Tags: magento2, product-list, pagination, product-listing

I need to make the pagination show some amount of pages saying 5 then show the dots and last page. Making it look like:

1 2 3 4 5 ... 20

pager.phtml already has those within the template, but they depend on the following methods

```
canShowNextJump();
canShowLast();
```

both are defined within `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager`

Is there any combination of Admin settings to achieve that or I will need to override methods/values in Pager block?

Comment: you want to pagination show this type `1 2 3 4 5 ... 20` ???

Comment: @MohitPatel, this has to look like `< 1 2 3 4 5 ... 20 > ` where '20' is the last page

Answer (score 0):

Add at Content > Design > Configuration > your Theme > Pagination > Pagination Frame Skip => 10 or try what is good for you
[image]

[image]